# tidyr Pivot-wider: Duplicate issue

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I am trying to use pivot wider to reduce the number of rows in my data and add new columns. However, the number of columns increases, but the number of rows remains the same. Ideally, each 'Indicator' should be one observation, where the DataYear, Company, Market, Country etc columns are the same. I think the issue may be due to duplicate observations, but dont understand how the IndicatorID column doesnt fix this issue?

A sample of my data:

```
    LongTest <- structure(list(DataYear = c(2018L, 2017L, 2016L, 2018L, 2017L, 
2016L, 2018L, 2017L, 2016L), Company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "One", class = "factor"), Market = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Total", class = "factor"), 
    Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ALL", class = "factor"), 
    ISO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ALL", class = "factor"), 
    Sector = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Insurance", class = "factor"), 
    Division = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Furtherdetails1 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Furtherdetails2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Indicator = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Tax Avoidance", 
    "Turnover"), class = "factor"), IndicatorID = c(20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 26L, 26L, 26L), InputName = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Number of employees", 
    "Profit before tax (Attributable to shareholder profit)", 
    "Tax Paid"), class = "factor"), InputCode = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("InputA", "InputB"
    ), class = "factor"), UnitRequired = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("#", "GBP"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(4.47e+08, 6.2e+08, 6.47e+08, 2.129e+09, 2.003e+09, 
    1.193e+09, 37628, 42431, 39833.44), UniqueID = 1:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

And the code I am currently using:

```
outTest <- pivot_wider(LongTest, names_from = InputCode, values_from = c(Value, UnitRequired, InputName))
```

When I use my full dataframe I get this error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Values in `InputName` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(InputName = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(InputName = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(InputName = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates 
2: Values in `UnitRequired` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(UnitRequired = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(UnitRequired = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(UnitRequired = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates 
3: Values in `Value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(Value = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(Value = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(Value = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
```

Ideal output would be something like this:

```
    structure(list(DataYear = c(2018L, 2017L, 2016L, 2018L, 2017L, 
2016L), Company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "One", class = "factor"), 
    Market = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Total", class = "factor"), 
    Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ALL", class = "factor"), 
    ISO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ALL", class = "factor"), 
    Sector = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Insurance", class = "factor"), 
    Division = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Furtherdetails1 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Furtherdetails2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Indicator = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Tax Avoidance", 
    "Turnover"), class = "factor"), IndicatorID = c(20L, 20L, 
    20L, 26L, 26L, 26L), Value_InputA = c(2129000000L, 2003000000L, 
    1193000000L, NA, NA, NA), InputName_InputA = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Profit before tax (Attributable to shareholder profit)"
    ), class = "factor"), UnitRequired_InputA = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "GBP"), class = "factor"), 
    Value_InputB = c(4.47e+08, 6.2e+08, 6.47e+08, 37628, 42431, 
    39833.44), InputName_InputB = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("Number of employees", "Tax Paid"), class = "factor"), 
    UnitRequired_InputB = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("#", 
    "GBP"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Do you need `LongTest %>%
  group_by(InputCode) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = InputCode, values_from = c(Value, UnitRequired, InputName))` ?

Comment: The answer from @Rui Barradas worked, but the duplicates were separated into multiple rows. If you want to keep your duplicated values, collapsed into 1 row per unique identifier, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61779844/14640641) worked for me. I don't fully understand what this code is doing, but it worked like a charm. P.S. I know this is a very late answer but I figured I'd include it anyway for anyone else who is searching for a solution to this issue and hasn't seen the other post yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @Ronak Shah's suggestion in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258879/tidyr-pivot-wider-duplicate-issue#comment106587871_60258879) to create a `row` column, the following seems to do it. I have added a second grouping column, `Indicator`.

```
library(tidyverse)

LongTest %>%
  group_by(InputCode, Indicator) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(row, Indicator),
              names_from = InputCode, 
              values_from = c(Value, UnitRequired, InputName)) %>%
  select(-row)
```