# Merging Duplicate Rows and apply Pivot_wider

Tags: r

I have the following dataset format:

```
structure(list(ï..Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("1/1/2019", "1/2/2019"), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AAA001", "BBB002"), class = "factor"), 
    Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FEMALE", 
    "MALE"), class = "factor"), Measure = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Mental Status", "Motor Function", 
    "No. 1", "Score"), class = "factor"), Value = structure(c(6L, 
    6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1.", "2/2/2020", "3811: Satisfactory", 
    "4", "7", "Normal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Output:

```
 df
  ï..Date     ID Gender        Measure              Value
1 1/1/2019 AAA001   MALE  Mental Status             Normal
2 1/1/2019 AAA001   MALE Motor Function             Normal
3 1/1/2019 AAA001   MALE          Score                  7
4 1/1/2019 BBB002 FEMALE          No. 1                 1.
5 1/1/2019 BBB002 FEMALE          No. 1           2/2/2020
6 1/1/2019 BBB002 FEMALE          No. 1 3811: Satisfactory
7 1/2/2019 BBB002 FEMALE          Score                  4
>
```

I tried the following but encountered errors, which came out with almost 7000 duplicates, mainly due to the duplicate rows of Measures for the same ID:

```
df %>%
+         distinct() %>%
+         pivot_wider(names_from = 'Measure', values_from = 'Value')
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  ï..Date  ID     Gender `Mental Status` `Motor Function`       Score     `No. 1`
  <fct>    <fct>  <fct>      <list<fct>>      <list<fct>> <list<fct>> <list<fct>>
1 1/1/2019 AAA001 MALE               [1]              [1]         [1]         [0]
2 1/1/2019 BBB002 FEMALE             [0]              [0]         [0]         [3]
3 1/2/2019 BBB002 FEMALE             [0]              [0]         [1]         [0]
Warning message:
Values in `Value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(Value = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(Value = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(Value = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
```

The expected output should be like the following:

```
      Date     ID Gender Mental.Status Motor.Function                            No.1 Score
1 1/1/2019 AAA001   MALE        Normal         Normal                                     7
2 1/1/2019 BBB002 FEMALE                              1. 2/2/2020, 3811: Satisfactory     4
```

Appreciate for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `summarize` to `paste` the values together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(`ï..Date`,`ID`,`Measure`) %>%
  summarize(Value = paste(Value, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'Measure', values_from = 'Value')
## A tibble: 3 x 6
#  ï..Date  ID     `Mental Status` `Motor Function` Score `No. 1`                         
#  <fct>    <fct>  <chr>           <chr>            <chr> <chr>                           
#1 1/1/2019 AAA001 Normal          Normal           7     NA                              
#2 1/1/2019 BBB002 NA              NA               NA    1., 2/2/2020, 3811: Satisfactory
#3 1/2/2019 BBB002 NA              NA               4     NA
```

Comment: Btw Ian, how should the results be output to another df, say df1?

Comment: Just change the first line to `df1 <- df %>%`